# The following assignment only causes a warning. What does this say about how C treats type equivalence?

Tags: c, pointers, assign, type-equivalence

The following assignment only causes a warning.  What does this say about how C treats type equivalence?

```
int *iptr;
float *fptr;
float fval;
fval = 0.0;
fptr = &fval;
iptr = fptr;
```

In particular, I'm referring to the assignment in the last line of the above snippet of code; namely,

```
iptr = fptr;
```

Comment: Because you're assigning a pointer to float to a pointer to int. Even if they have same size they're not same type and when you'll access iptr you'll treat raw float value as an integer (but, for example, representation of 1.1 won't be "1"). But maybe you know this so...what's your question? Why your C compiler allows this without an explicit cast?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It says more about the behavior of the compiler you're using than about C, though the compiler's behavior is (unfortunately IMHO) permitted by the C standard.

The types `int*` and `float*` are distinct, and the language defines no implicit conversion between them.

Attempting to assign one to the other without a cast (i.e., an explicit type conversion) is a *constraint violation*, which means that a compiler is required to issue a diagnostic message.

The C standard does not require such a diagnostic to be fatal. By issuing a warning, your compiler has done its job as far as the C standard is concerned. It could, with equal validity, have rejected your program (and in my opinion that would have been more user-friendly). But either behavior is conforming.

You can probably invoke your compiler in a way to make it treat this as a fatal error. For example, if you're using gcc the `-pedantic-errors` option (along with an option to specify which version of the C standard to use) should do the trick.

If you really want to perform that assignment (with all the risks that entails), you can use a cast:

```
iptr = (int*)fptr;
```

In addition to (probably) turning off the compiler warning, a pointer cast should act as a reminder that you're doing something tricky, and it may blow up in your face if you don'w know *exactly* what you're doing.